# Extract unique elements in each row of a matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, unique

I have a large matrix filled with integers. I would like to create a second matrix that contains the same information but removes all duplicates by row and replaces them with zeros.

For example, I need to convert the following matrix:

Row 1:[1,2,3,2,3,4]
Row 2:[3,4,2,2,1,6]

to:

Row 1: [1,2,3,0,0,4]
Row 2: [3,4,2,0,1,6].

I can do this very easily using a loop but since I'm working with large data, I'm attempting to avoid a loop. Is there any way to do this?

I'm new to R so hopefully this all made sense. I appreciate any and all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `duplicated` with `apply`

```
m1[] <- t(apply(m1, 1, function(x) replace(x, duplicated(x), 0)))
```

---

Or more compactly

```
t(!apply(m1, 1, duplicated)) * m1
```

#### Data

```
m1 <- rbind(c(1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4), c(3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 6))
```